# How to remedy rock-hard sugar-free ice cream

Tags: ice-cream, texture, sugar-free

I am making sugar free ice cream, however I obviously have run into many issues.

The first is that my ice cream is freezing hard as a rock when left overnight. When reading the forums on many websites I see that this could be due to a lack of stabilizers mainly being sugar. Since I have no sugar in my ice cream, I cannot figure out what substitute to implement. I'm sticking to the sugar free aspect with all of the ingredients. I have three questions that pertain to this:

1. Do I need to use guar gum in conjunction with Xantham Gum to not have the ice cream freeze like a rock?
2. Are there oils I can add to increase stabilization in place of the sugar by adding essential fats?
3. Are there any stabilizers that I can add to achieve the proper stabilization that sugar would have in the ice cream?

Comment: You should sketch your recipe so we can understand what you are doing.

Comment: What are the " many" issues other than hardness? Could you also expand on "sugar free aspect with all the ingredients" - do you mean you chose all other ingredients that are also sugar-free? What are these other ingredients?

Comment: Are you adding eggs, or is this egg free too?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it´s lacking stabilizers that are causing the hardness of your mixture.

The softness of ice cream is a result of a share (typically around 70%) of the contained water being frozen to microscopic ice crystals while another part remains liquid. To keep this share of water liquid below 0°C it is required to lower the freezing point and this is done by dissolving sugars in the mix, because they consist of small molecules which will freeze on a lower temperature than the larger molecules of the water. So if sugar-free only relates to sucrose (the usual household sugar) switching to another type of sugar like dextrose or fructose could be an option, if not, you will have to look for another ingredient with a small molecule size to get the freezing point down, like alcohol. Be aware that all these options come with different PAC (potere anticongelante, freezing inhibition power) value, so that you can not simply exchange them by a 1:1-ratio but will have to re-balance your mix.